# tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint Type Error : Unable to serialize 1.0000000656873453e-05 to JSON

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras, checkpoint

I am creating my custom layers tf.keras model using mobile net pretrained layer. Model training is running fine but when saving the best picked model it is giving an error. Below is the snippet of the code that I used

```
pretrained_model = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(
                                                    weights='imagenet',
                                                    include_top=False,
                                                    input_shape=[*IMAGE_SIZE, IMG_CHANNELS])
pretrained_model.trainable = True #fine tuning
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
                            tf.keras.layers.Lambda(# Convert image from int[0, 255] to the format expect by this model
                            lambda data:tf.keras.applications.mobilenet.preprocess_input(
                                tf.cast(data, tf.float32)), input_shape=[*IMAGE_SIZE, 3]),
                            pretrained_model,
                            tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()])

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, name='object_dense',kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(l2=0.001)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(scale=False, center = False))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu', name='relu_dense_64'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.2, name='dropout_dense_64'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, name='object_dense_2',kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(l2=0.01)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(scale=False, center = False))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu', name='relu_dense_32'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.2, name='dropout_dense_32'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, name='object_dense_16', kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(l2=0.01)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(len(CLASS_NAMES), activation='softmax', name='object_prob'))
m1 = tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy()
m2 = tf.keras.metrics.Recall()
m3 = tf.keras.metrics.Precision()



optimizers = [
    tfa.optimizers.AdamW(learning_rate=lr * .001 , weight_decay=wd),
    tfa.optimizers.AdamW(learning_rate=lr, weight_decay=wd)
           ]

optimizers_and_layers = [(optimizers[0], model.layers[0]), (optimizers[1], model.layers[1:])]

optimizer = tfa.optimizers.MultiOptimizer(optimizers_and_layers)

model.compile(
    optimizer= optimizer,
    loss = 'categorical_crossentropy',
    metrics=[m1, m2, m3],
    )

checkpoint_path = os.getcwd() + os.sep + 'keras_model'
checkpoint_cb = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath=os.path.join(checkpoint_path), 
                                                    monitor = 'categorical_accuracy',
                                                    save_best_only=True,
                                                    save_weights_only=True)

history = model.fit(train_data, validation_data=test_data, epochs=N_EPOCHS, callbacks=[checkpoint_cb])
```

At tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint is giving me an error

**TypeError: Unable to serialize 1.0000000656873453e-05 to JSON. Unrecognized type <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor'>.**

Below is the link to the Google Colab notebook in case you want to replicate the issue

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1wQbUFfhtDaB5Xta574UkAXJtthui7Bt9?usp=sharing

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be a bug in Tensorflow or Keras. The tensor that's being serialized to JSON is from your optimizer definition.

```py
model.optimizer.optimizer_specs[0]["optimizer"].get_config()["weight_decay"]

<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=1.0000001e-05>
```

From the [implementation](https://github.com/tensorflow/addons/blob/8cec33fcaaf1cf90aec7bdd55a0fcdbb251ce5c2/tensorflow_addons/optimizers/weight_decay_optimizers.py#L91) of `tfa.optimizers.AdamW`, the `weight_decay` is serialized using `tf.keras.optimizers.Adam._serialize_hyperparameter`. This function assumes that if you pass in a callable for the hyperparameter, it returns a non-tensor value when called, but in your notebook, it was implemented as

```py
wd = lambda: 1e-02 * schedule(step)
```

where `schedule()` returns a Tensor. I tried some various ways to try to convert the tensor to a scalar value, but I couldn't get them to work. As a workaround, I implemented `wd` as a [`LearningRateSchedule`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/2c48a3b38b6b6139be2da501982fd2f61d7d48fe/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py#L1069) so it'll serialize properly, though the code was clunkier. Replacing the definitions of `wd` and `lr` with this code allowed model training to complete for me without any issues.

```py
class MyExponentialDecay(tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.ExponentialDecay):
  def __call__(self, step):
    return 1e-2 * super().__call__(step)

wd = MyExponentialDecay(
    initial_learning_rate,
    decay_steps=14,
    decay_rate=0.8,
    staircase=True)
lr = 1e2 * schedule(step)
```

After training completes, the `model.save()` call will fail. I believe this is the same issue which was reported [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/addons/issues/2446) in the Tensorflow Addons Github. The summary of this issue is  that the `get_config()` function for the optimizers will include a `"gv"` key in the config which stores `Tensor` objects, which aren't JSON serializable.

At the time of writing, this issue has not been resolved yet. If you don't need the optimizer state for the final saved model, you can pass in the `include_optimizer=False` argument to `model.save()` which worked for me. Otherwise, you may need to patch the library or the specific optimizer class implementation to get rid of the `"gw"` key in the config like the OP did in that thread.